# call async_resolve.cancel(),but the callback handler of async_resolve doesn't return boost::asio::error::operation_aborted

Tags: boost, boost-asio

i used boost asio to process http request and answer,to avoid async_resolve doesn't invoke its callback handler,i set a timeout,just like this:

```
void resolve()
{
  resolver_.async_resolve(query,strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&connection::handle_resolve,
                          shared_from_this(),
                          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                          boost::asio::placeholders::iterator)));
  int cancel_num = timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(resolve_timeout_));
  timer_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&connection::handle_resolve_timeout,
                    shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error)));
}


void connection::handle_resolve_timeout(const boost::system::error_code& err)
{
  if (err != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
  {
      resolver_.cancel();
  }
}

void connection::handle_resolve(const boost::system::error_code& err,
                    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
{
  timer_.cancel();
  if(!err)
  {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *endpoint_iterator;
    socket_.async_connect(endpoint,strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&connection::handle_connect,
                  shared_from_this(),
                  boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                  ++endpoint_iterator)));
    //to distinct the type of timeout ,0:connect timeout,1:read timeout
    int flag = 0;
    int cancel_num = timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(connect_timeout_));
    timer_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(boost::bind(&connection::handle_timeout,
                      shared_from_this(),
                      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                      flag)));
  }
  else if(err != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
  {
    status_ = resolve_error;
    check_.do_finish(shared_from_this());
  }
  else
  {
    FASTCHECK_INFO("resolve is canceled\n");
  }
}
```

when resolve timeout ,i found the handle_resolve_timeout is invoked,but the handle_resolve doesn't return boost::asio::error::operation_aborted,why,i am puzzled,can someone can explain it for me?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [discussion on boost-users](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2007/06/28647.php) mailing list, `resolver::cancel()` is only able to cancel pending, queued resolve requests, not the one that's currently executing.

Comment: yes,i try to set resolve_timeout=10s or 1s,then invoke cancel in handle_resolve_timeout,but the handle_resolve still be invoked after a few seconds with no boost::asio::error::operation_aborted error,i think you are right,maybe the handle_resolve is set uncancel status before resolve::cancel being invoked,so cancel doesn't work,but async_connect or async_read_XX is not the case.thank you,it's the only explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As a delayed follow up to @Cubbi's answer, this bug was also raised on the [Boost issue tracker](https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/6138) a few months after this question's thread. The Asio resolver API is slightly confusing because it suggests that any `async_resolve()` operation can be cancelled on demand. I had the same problem myself. It also turns out that in the Asio implementation, calls to `async_resolve()` makes a synchronous system call to `getaddrinfo()` behind the scenes. I discuss this interesting behavior in a [recent codecast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03eMoHBK_eM).

Comment: The synchronous `getaddrinfo()` is actually performed in a dedicated worker thread, that `boost::asio::ip::resolve` creates on the first call and then keeps around to use it again.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note and to explain things a bit further: `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::async_resolve()` creates a single background thread to do the actual name resolutions, which are performed one by one using the system C library's `getaddrinfo()` call. Even, if you create multiple `resolver` objects in your application, ALL your asynchronous resolve requests are serialized and forwarded to that single thread.

The advantage of that implementation is, that calls to `async_resolve()` do not block any other `async()` methods, despite that `getaddrinfo()` is blocking. The downside is, though, that all calls to `async_resolve()` block each other! So, if an application needs to resolve 100 host names and DNS has hickups and the lookup takes five seconds on average, then the application start up time will be 500 seconds. Also, if a particular DNS server is currently unreachable, that lookup will hang until `getaddrinfo()` times out. And no, `resolver::cancel()` has no effect on that current lookup, as `getaddrinfo()` is not cancellable.

There are a few ways to improve this situation:

1. Applications, that need to perform a large number of address resolutions, can use a dedicated `io_context` with a dedicated thread pool, in which they perform *synchronous* address resolutions. Then one can have at least as many parallel `getaddrinfo()` calls, as there are threads in that resolver thread pool.
2. A somewhat small upgrade to the current implementation could add the feature to signal a blocked resolver thread, that its result are no longer needed and that it should exit as soon as possible, and then `detach()` that thread and forget about it. The next name resolution will then create a new thread. This will allow applications to immediately `cancel()` the current active lookup (for example, when a deadline timer fires) and move on to the next lookup immediately (which will be started in a new thread). Nonetheless, the detached "daemon" thread will still try to complete its `getaddrinfo()` call, and if it does so, the results will usually be cached somewhere in the system. When the application retries that particular outgoing connection a few seconds later, the cached result will be used to answer the resolver request immediately and the connection can then succeed.
3. At least for systems using `glibc` like Linux, `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver` could be upgraded to use the GNU extension `getaddrinfo_a()`, which truly parallelizes name resolutions. Unfortunately, `getaddrinfo_a()` suffers from similar weaknesses as the `select()` system call, as the overhead for calls to `gai_suspend()` (which reads one or more results of background `getaddrinfo_a()` requests) increases quadratically with the number of unfinished name resolutions. And even more unfortunate, it is unclear, how (in)efficiently `getaddrinfo_a()` is actually implemented. The white paper from the people at RedHat, that implemented it, suggests, that it uses a thread pool around `getaddrinfo()`, at least for the more complicated cases. So actually, using `getaddrinfo_a()` might be as good or bad as the solution 1 above.